# Overload resolution between constructors and conversion operators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

I have a couple of questions related to overload resolution in C++. Consider this example:

```
extern "C" int printf (const char*, ...);                                       
                                                                                
struct X {};                                                                    
                                                                                
template <typename T>                                                           
struct A                                                                        
{                                                                               
    A() = default;                                                              
                                                                                
    template <typename U>                                                       
    A(A<U>&&)                                                                   
    {printf("%s \n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);}                                     
};                                                                              
                                                                                
template <typename T>                                                           
struct B : A<T>                                                                 
{                                                                               
    B() = default;                                                              
                                                                                
    template <typename U>                                                       
    operator A<U>()                                                             
    {printf("%s \n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); return {};}                          
};                                                                              
                                                                                
int main ()                                                                     
{                                                                               
    A<X> a1 (B<int>{});                                                         
}
```

If I compile it with `g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp`, the `A`'s constructor will get called:

```
A<T>::A(A<U>&&) [with U = int; T = X]
```

If I compile program with `g++ -std=c++17 a.cpp`, it will produce

```
B<T>::operator A<U>() [with U = X; T = int]
```

If I comment `A(A<U>&&)` out and once again compile it with `g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp`, the conversion operator will be called:

```
B<T>::operator A<U>() [with U = X; T = int]
```

- Why is the conversion operator even considered in the third case? Why is the program not ill-formed? [dcl.init] states:

> Otherwise, **if the initialization is direct-initialization**, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, **constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (16.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (16.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object**, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s). **If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.**

- Why `A`'s constructor is the better choice in the first case?`B`'s conversion operator seems to be the better match since it doesn't require an implicit conversion from `B<int>` to `A<int>`.
- Why the first and second cases yield different results? What has changed in C++17?

P.S. Does anyone know where I can find a detailed guide that describes how conversion operators participate in overload resolution, i.e., the ways they interact with the constructors when different types of initialization take place. I know that the standard provides the most accurate description, but it seems that my interpretation of the standard wording has little in common with its correct meaning. Some kind of rule of thumb and additional examples might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `A`'s constructor is the better choice in the first case? `B`'s conversion operator seems to be the better match since it doesn't require an implicit conversion from `B<int>` to `A<int>`.

I believe this choice is due to the open standard issue report [CWG 2327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2327):

> #### 2327. Copy elision for direct-initialization with a conversion function
>
> **Section:** 11.6  [dcl.init]
>
> **Status:** drafting
>
> **Submitter:** Richard Smith
>
> **Date:** 2016-09-30
>
> Consider an example like:
>
> ```
> struct Cat {};
> struct Dog { operator Cat(); };
>
> Dog d;
> Cat c(d);
> ```
>
> This goes to 11.6 [dcl.init] bullet 17.6.2: [...]
>
> Overload resolution selects the move constructor of `Cat`. Initializing the `Cat&&` parameter of the constructor results in a temporary, per 11.6.3 [dcl.init.ref] bullet 5.2.1.2. **This precludes the possitiblity of copy elision for this case.**
>
> This seems to be **an oversight in the wording change for guaranteed copy elision.** We should presumably be simultaneously **considering both constructors and conversion functions in this case, as we would for copy-initialization**, but we'll need to make sure that doesn't introduce any novel problems or ambiguities..

We may note that it both GCC and Clang picks the conversion operator (even though the issue is not yet a resolved DR) from versions 7.1 and 6.0, respectively (for C++17 language level); prior to these releases both GCC and Clang chose the `A<X>::A(A<U> &&) [T = X, U = int]` ctor overload.

> Why the first and second cases yield different results? What has changed in C++17?

C++17 introduced guaranteed copy elision, meaning the compiler *must* omit the copy and move construction of class objects (even if they have side effects) under certain circumstances; if the argument in the issue above hold, this is such a circumstance.

---

Notably, [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-dr-status.html) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) both lists unknown (/or none) status of CWG 2327; possibly as the issue is it still in status *Drafting*.

---

#### C++17: guaranteed copy/move elision & aggregate initialization of user-declared constructors

The following program is well-formed in C++17:

```
struct A {                                                                               
    A() = delete;                                                            
    A(const A&) = delete;         
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;                                 
};                                                                              
                                                                                                                                  
struct B {                                                                               
    B() = delete;                                                         
    B(const B&) = delete;         
    B(B&&) = delete;
    B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
    B& operator=(B&&) = delete;  
                                                    
    operator A() { return {}; }                          
};                                                                              
                                                                                
int main ()                                                                     
{   
    //A a;   // error; default initialization (deleted ctor)
    A a{}; // OK before C++20: aggregate initialization
    
    // OK int C++17 but not C++20: 
    // guaranteed copy/move elision using aggr. initialization
    // in user defined B to A conversion function.
    A a1 (B{});                                                         
}
```

which may come as a surprise. The core rule here is that both `A` and `B` are aggregates (and may thus be initialized by means of aggregate initialization) as they do not contain user-*provided* constructors, only (explicitly-deleted) user-*declared* ones.

#### C++20 guaranteed copy/move elision & stricter rules for aggregate initialization

As of [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf), which has been adopted for C++20, the snippet above is ill-formed, as `A` and `B` are no longer aggregates as they have user-*declared* ctors; prior to P1008R1 the requirement were weaker, and only for types not to have user-*provided* ctors.

If we declare `A` and `B` to have explicitly-defaulted definitions, the program is naturally well-formed.

```
struct A {                                                                               
    A() = default;                                                            
    A(const A&) = delete;         
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;                                 
};                                                                              
                                                                                                                                  
struct B {                                                                               
    B() = default;                                                         
    B(const B&) = delete;         
    B(B&&) = delete;
    B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
    B& operator=(B&&) = delete;  
                                                    
    operator A() { return {}; }                          
};                                                                              
                                                                                
int main ()                                                                     
{   
    // OK: guaranteed copy/move elision.
    A a1 (B{});                                                         
}
```

Comment: Ok, let's say GCC and Clang both decided to implement it in C++17. But I can remove `A(A<U>&&)` and it still works in C++11. Why then the conversion operator is a viable choice in C++11? From my point of view, it shouldn't compile.

Comment: By the way, why does the conversion operator better suit the purposes of copy elision than constructors?

Comment: @BaykovNikita When you remove the user-declared move ctor, you will fulfil the requirements for the compiler to generate a move ctor for you implicitly. If you, instead of _omitting_ you user-declared move ctor actually _delete_ the move ctor, `A(A<T>&&) = delete;` the program will be ill-formed in C++11, but be valid in C++17 (due to guaranteed copy/move elision). In C++17, you can even explicitly delete the default ctor, the copy ctor and assignment operator and the move ctor and assignment operator, and your example will _still_ be well-formed, as the conversion op. elides copying/moving.

Comment: dfri, do you mean that the implicitly-generated move constructor will be chosen by overload resolution and the conversion operator will be a part of the conversion sequence that creates a temporary and uses it as the constructor's argument?

Comment: @BaykovNikita In pre-C++17: exactly. Even if it _may_ be elided, it needs to be defined as it _may not_ be elided and thus part of the conversion sequence from "user defined conversion function `B<int>` to [temporary] `A<X>` followed by (possibly elided) move-construction to [lvalue] `A<X>`".

Comment: @BaykovNikita Note also that the inheritance in your example is not significant, and we can just as well remove it to remove some confusion. Peculiarly we can, in C++17 (GCC and Clang) actually explicitly delete all otherwise implicitly declared ctors and assignment operators for _both_ `A` and `B`, and [_still_ be able to construct an `A` object from a `B` object](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dll8gOA6RAk14tCb). This is flagged as an error in C++2a, and kind of seems like a defect to me in C++17.

Comment: And indeed (regarding my previous comment), the example I link to leverages that aggregate initialization is allowed even for user-defined classes with explicitly-deleted default constructors. This has been addressed in C++20 as per [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf).